# Navigation position "absolute" not working

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to move the Navigation position "menu" to the top, check the pic:

[image]

```
.site-header-layout-two .main-navigation {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    top: 1px;
}
```

But if I change the top value or bottom value automatically the menu will stuck at the bottom.

Am I doing it wrong! or there is other code line conflict with this one! Here is my full code if you want to check other things:

```
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust:     100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}

audio,
canvas,
progress,
video {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}

[hidden],
template {
  display: none;
}

a {
  background-color: transparent;
}

a:active,
a:hover {
  outline: 0;
}

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}

dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}

mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

img {
  border: 0;
}

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}

figure {
  margin: 1em 40px;
}

hr {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
}

pre {
  overflow: auto;
}

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  font-size: 1em;
}

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

button {
  overflow: visible;
}

button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}

button,
html input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input {
  line-height: normal;
}

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}

input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

legend {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
}

optgroup {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 0;
}

/*---------
# Typography
----------*/
body,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  color: #808080;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  clear: both;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 25px;
}

dfn,
cite,
em,
i {
  font-style: italic;
}

blockquote {
  margin: 0 1.5em;
}

address {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}

pre {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: "Courier 10 Pitch", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  line-height: 1.6;
  margin-bottom: 1.6em;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1.6em;
}

code,
kbd,
tt,
var {
  font-family: Monaco, Consolas, "Andale Mono", "DejaVu Sans Mono", monospace;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
}

abbr,
acronym {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #666;
  cursor: help;
}

mark,
ins {
  background: #fff9c0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

big {
  font-size: 125%;
}



/*---------
# Elements
----------*/
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after { /* Inherit box-sizing to make it easier to change the property for components that leverage other behavior; see http://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/ */
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background: #FFF; /* Fallback for when there is no custom background color defined. */
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: cover;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: "";
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: "" "";
}

hr {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

ul,
ol {
    margin: 0 0 25px 20px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
ul li,
ol li {
    margin: 0 0 12px;
}

ul {
    list-style: disc;
}

ol {
    list-style: decimal;
}

li > ul,
li > ol {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}

dt {
    font-weight: bold;
}

dd {
    margin: 0 1.5em 1.5em;
}

img {
    height: auto; /* Make sure images are scaled correctly. */
    max-width: 100%; /* Adhere to container width. */
}

figure {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
}

table {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
}

th {
    font-weight: bold;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a {
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.0em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    color: #5E5E5E;
    margin-top: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 32px;
    margin-bottom: .55em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-bottom: .65em;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-bottom: .8em;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 1.1em;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 1.3em;
}

h6 {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 1.4em;
}

.entry-content code {
    display: block;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
    margin: 5px 0;
    overflow-x: auto;
}


/*------------
# Navigation
------------*/
/*-----------
## Links
---------------*/
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

a:visited {
}

a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {

}

a:focus {

}

a:hover,
a:active {
  outline: 0;
}

/*---------
## Menus
---------*/

.main-navigation ul {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.main-navigation li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.main-navigation li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #FFF;
}
.main-navigation li a span {
    display: none;
}
.main-navigation ul ul {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 57px;
    left: -999em;
    z-index: 99999;
    display: none;
}
.main-navigation ul ul a {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 25px 15px 20px;
    min-width: 190px;
    float: none;
}
.main-navigation ul ul ul {
    top: 1px;
}
.main-navigation ul ul li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}
.main-navigation li:hover > a,
.main-navigation li.focus > a {
}

.main-navigation ul ul :hover > a,
.main-navigation ul ul .focus > a {
}

.main-navigation ul ul a:hover,
.main-navigation ul ul a.focus {
}

.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul,
.main-navigation ul li.focus > ul {
  left: 0;
  display: block;
}

.main-navigation ul ul li:hover > ul,
.main-navigation ul ul li.focus > ul {
  right: 100%;
}

.main-navigation .current_page_item > a,
.main-navigation .current-menu-item > a,
.main-navigation .current_page_ancestor > a {
}

/* Small menu. */
.menu-toggle,
.main-navigation.toggled ul {
  display: block;
}

#main-menu:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    clear: both;
}

.header-menu-button {
    display: none;
}

.menu-dropdown-btn {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    color: #838383;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 14px;
    /* box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08); */
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: 9;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.site-main .comment-navigation,
.site-main .posts-navigation,
.site-main .post-navigation {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.comment-navigation .nav-previous,
.posts-navigation .nav-previous,
.post-navigation .nav-previous {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.comment-navigation .nav-next,
.posts-navigation .nav-next,
.post-navigation .nav-next {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  width: 50%;
}

/* Small menu */
.menu-toggle {
    display: none;
}

.main-menu-close {
    display: none;
}

/*-----------
# Accessibility
-------------*/
/* Text meant only for screen readers. */
.screen-reader-text {
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  position: absolute !important;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.screen-reader-text:hover,
.screen-reader-text:active,
.screen-reader-text:focus {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  clip: auto !important;
  color: #21759b;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: auto;
  left: 5px;
  line-height: normal;
  padding: 15px 23px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  top: 5px;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 100000; /* Above WP toolbar. */
}

/*--------------
# Alignments
---------------*/
.alignleft {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}

.alignright {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}

.aligncenter {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

/*-------------
# Clearings
--------------*/
.clear:before,
.clear:after,
.entry-content:before,
.entry-content:after,
.comment-content:before,
.comment-content:after,
.site-header:before,
.site-header:after,
.site-content:before,
.site-content:after,
.site-footer:before,
.site-footer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clear:after,
.entry-content:after,
.comment-content:after,
.site-header:after,
.site-content:after,
.site-footer:after {
  clear: both;
}



/* -------- Header Elements -------- */

.site-header {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
}
.site-header-layout-two .site-header {
    box-shadow: 0 -6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset;
    padding: 0 0 5px;
}
.site-header .site-container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1280px;
}
.header-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
}

.header-social-icon {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: inherit;
    margin: 2px 0 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.site-branding {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 12;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
.site-branding-img {
  padding: 0;
}
.site-branding a {
    display: block;
    line-height: inherit;
}
.site-branding a img {
    display: block;
}
.site-title {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.site-description {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: inherit;
}
.site-header-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    margin: -70px 0 0;
    text-align: right;
}
.site-header-right-txt {
    margin: -52px 0 0;
}
.site-header-right-no-txt {
    margin: -70px 0 0;
}
.site-header-right-no-ss {
    margin: -38px 0 0;
}
.site-header-right-no-sst {
    margin: -58px 0 0;
}
.site-header-signup {

}
.site-header-cart {

}
.site-header-right-top {min-height: 36px;}
.site-topbar-right-no {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #FFF;
    padding: 0 0 5px;
}
.site-topbar-right-no i.fa {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 2px 0 4px;
}
.site-topbar-right-no span {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
}
.site-header-right-bottom {
    padding: 6px 0 0;
}
.site-header-social {
    padding: 2px 0 0;
}
.social-pinterest span {
    font-size: 11px;
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
    margin: 0 0 0 4px;
}

.header-cart {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0;
}
.header-cart a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: inherit;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
a.header-cart-contents {
    color: inherit !important;
}
.header-cart-amount {

}
.header-cart-checkout {
    margin: 0 0 0 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
}





#main-menu {
    text-align: center;
}
.main-navigation {
    padding: 0;

    -webkit-transition: right 0.4s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: right 0.4s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: right 0.4s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: right 0.4s ease 0s;
    transition: right 0.4s ease 0s;
}
.site-header-layout-one .main-navigation {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
}
.site-header-layout-one .main-navigation li a {
    padding: 18px 20px 18px;
}
.site-header-layout-one .main-navigation ul ul li a {
    padding: 14px 25px 16px;
}
.main-navigation ul ul li {
    position: relative;
}
.main-navigation ul ul ul {
}
.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul,
.main-navigation ul li.focus > ul {
    right: auto;
    left: 0;
}
.main-navigation ul ul li:hover > ul,
.main-navigation ul ul li.focus > ul {
    right: auto;
    left: 100%;
}

/* -------- Header Layout Two -------- */

.site-top-bar {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.site-top-bar-left {
    float: left;
    padding: 2px 0 0;
    min-height: 31px;
}
.site-top-bar-right {
    float: right;
    padding: 2px 0 0;
    min-height: 31px;
}
.site-header-layout-two {
}
.site-header-layout-two .header-social-icon {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
.site-header-layout-two .site-topbar-right-no {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: inherit;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 12px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
.site-header-layout-two .site-topbar-right-no span {
    font-size: inherit;
}

.site-header-layout-two .main-navigation {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}
.site-header-layout-two .main-navigation li {
    margin: 0;
}
.site-header-layout-two .main-navigation li a {
    padding: 55px 25px 60px;
}
.site-header-layout-two .main-navigation ul li:last-child a {
    padding: 55px 0 60px 25px;
}

.site-header-layout-two .main-navigation ul ul li a {
    padding: 14px 25px 16px !important;
}
.site-header-layout-two .main-navigation ul ul {
    top: 130px;
    border-top: 6px solid #000;
}
.site-header-layout-two .main-navigation ul ul ul {
    top: 1px;
    border: 0;
}

.sabino-header-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: -1px 8px 0 0;
}
.sabino-header-nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.sabino-header-nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.sabino-header-nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0px 3px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    color: inherit;
}
.sabino-header-nav ul li:first-child a {
    padding: 0px 3px 0 0;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
}

body.show-site-search .search-block {
    display: block;
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Infinite scroll
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Globally hidden elements when Infinite Scroll is supported and in use. */
.infinite-scroll .posts-navigation, /* Older / Newer Posts Navigation (always hidden) */
.infinite-scroll.neverending .site-footer { /* Theme Footer (when set to scrolling) */
  display: none;
}

/* When Infinite Scroll has reached its end we need to re-display elements that were hidden (via .neverending) before. */
.infinity-end.neverending .site-footer {
  display: block;
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Galleries
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.gallery {
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

.gallery-item {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery-columns-2 .gallery-item {
  max-width: 50%;
}

.gallery-columns-3 .gallery-item {
  max-width: 33.33%;
}

.gallery-columns-4 .gallery-item {
  max-width: 25%;
}

.gallery-columns-5 .gallery-item {
  max-width: 20%;
}

.gallery-columns-6 .gallery-item {
  max-width: 16.66%;
}

.gallery-columns-7 .gallery-item {
  max-width: 14.28%;
}

.gallery-columns-8 .gallery-item {
  max-width: 12.5%;
}

.gallery-columns-9 .gallery-item {
  max-width: 11.11%;
}

.gallery-caption {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {

    .menu-dropdown-btn {
        display: block;
    }
    .header-menu-button {
        display: block;
        padding: 14px 0 16px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 17px;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .header-menu-button i {
        font-size: 17px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .header-menu-button span {
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin: 0 0 0 6px;
    }
    .site-header-layout-two .header-menu-button {
        padding: 48px 0 60px 80px;
    }

    .main-navigation #main-menu {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: -280px;
        width: 280px;
        max-width: 100%;
        -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 82px 22px 30px 22px;
        background: #000000;
        z-index: 99998;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        transition: right 0.4s ease 0s;
    }
    .main-navigation li {
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
    .main-navigation li a {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        padding: 8px 0 !important;
        color: #C5C5C5 !important;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .main-navigation ul ul {
        position: relative !important;
        top: 0 !important;
        left: 0 !important;
        float: none !important;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.14) !important;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        display: none !important;
    }
    .main-navigation ul ul li:last-child a,
    .main-navigation ul ul li a {
        padding: 7px 10px;
        width: auto;
    }
    .main-navigation ul ul li a {
        background: none !important;
    }

    #primary-menu {
        display: block;
    }
    .main-menu-close {
        display: block;
        border-radius: 4px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #898989;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0 8px 0 12px;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 38px;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 99;
    }
    .main-menu-close .fa-angle-left {
        position: relative;
        left: -4px;
    }
    li.open-page-item > ul.children,
    li.open-page-item > ul.sub-menu {
        display: block !important;
    }

    body.admin-bar .main-menu-close {
        top: 52px;
    }
    body.admin-bar .header-cart {
        top: 55px;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 880px) {

    .post-loop-thumbnail {
        float: none !important;
        width: 100% !important;
    }
    .post-loop-content {
        float: none !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        padding: 20px 5px 0 !important;
    }

    .content-layout-blocks .sabino-blog-breakup .post-loop-thumbnail {
        position: relative !important;
        height: 400px !important;
    }
    .content-layout-blocks .sabino-blog-breakup .post-loop-content {
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 20px !important;
    }
    .content-layout-blocks .sabino-blog-breakup .blog-top-layout .post-loop-thumbnail {
        height: auto !important;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 782px) {

    .page-template-default .content-area,
    .woocommerce #container,
    .woocommerce-page #container,
    .content-area {
        box-shadow: none;
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
        padding: 25px 0 30px;
    }
    .content-layout-blocks.content-joined-widgets .content-area,
    .content-layout-blocks.content-joined-widgets #container,
    .content-layout-blocks.content-broken-widgets .content-area,
    .content-layout-blocks.content-broken-widgets #container {
        box-shadow: none;
        width: 100%;
        float: none !important;
        padding: 25px 20px 30px;
    }
    .content-layout-blocks .site-container-main {
        padding: 0 20px;
    }

    .page-template-default .widget-area,
    .widget-area,
    .content-layout-blocks.content-broken-widgets .widget-area {
        box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
        padding: 0 0 5px !important;
        margin: 0 0 10px;
    }
    .page-template-template-left-sidebar-php .content-area {
        box-shadow: none;
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
        padding: 25px 0 30px;
    }
    .page-template-template-left-sidebar-php .widget-area,
    .page-template-template-left-sidebar-php .content-layout-blocks.content-broken-widgets .widget-area {
        box-shadow: none;
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
        padding: 0 0 5px;
        margin: 0 0 10px;
    }

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------
    Header One Styling
    --------------------------------------------------------------*/
    .site-branding {
        float: none;
        padding: 10px 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .site-header-right {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        top: auto;
        right: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .site-header-right-top {
        min-height: initial;
    }
    .site-header-right-bottom {
        padding: 0 0 5px;
    }

    .site-header-layout-two .main-navigation {
        position: relative;
        right: auto;
    }
    .site-header-layout-two .header-menu-button {
        padding: 5px 0 15px;
    }

    .site-top-bar-left {
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
        min-height: 20px;
    }
    .site-top-bar-right {
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 2px 0 2px;
    }

    .search-block {
        position: relative;
        top: 0 !important;
        right: 0;
        padding: 12px;
    }
    .search-block .search-field {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .site-footer-standard .site-footer-widgets .site-container > ul {
        display: block;
    }
    .site-footer-standard .site-footer-widgets .site-container > ul > li {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px 0 20px !important;
    }

    .site-footer-bottom-bar-left,
    .site-footer-bottom-bar-right {
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
    }

}

body.show-main-menu #main-menu {
    right: 0px !important;
}
body.show-main-menu #page {
    right: 280px !important;
}
```

Comment: Can't help you without the HTML.

Comment: remove `bottom: 0;`. I think it will solve your problem. but, please upload it to a JSFiddle so we can help you efficiently

Comment: You might want to set the containing element .site-header-layout-two as position: relative;

Comment: @waxi the website is online, #italy I tried that still not working, #rmaspero I change it to "relative" and added "float: right;" seems that's gonna work! still working on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change below class, reduce the padding

```
.site-header-layout-two .main-navigation li a {
    padding: 19px 25px 6px;
}
```

and remove below code

```
.site-header-layout-two .main-navigation ul li:last-child a {
    padding: 55px 0 60px 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try setting `float: left;` on the "Martcor" logo, and `float: right;` on you navigation items on the right side.

Comment: I liked the idea! I will check that too